# Find the solutions of $\tanh(z)=i$ in the form of $(x +iy)$

Tags: complex-analysis

This question looks short and simple but I still unable to solve it. Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the definition of $\tanh(x)$ is

$$\tanh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$

Equalizing to $i$ y making some operations, we have

$$e^x-e^{-x}=i(e^x+ e^{-x}) \Rightarrow e^x(1-i)=e^{-x}(1+i)$$

$$e^{2x}=\frac{1+i}{1-i}=i \Rightarrow x=\frac{1}{2}\ln(i)$$

Remember that in complex analysis the logarithm is defined as

$$\ln z=\ln |z|+i\text{Arg} z+2k\pi i,$$

where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\text{Arg} z$ is the unique real number $\alpha$ contained in $[-\pi,\pi)$ which satisfies

$$z=|z|(\cos \alpha+i\sin \alpha).$$

For our case

$$x=\frac{1}{2}\ln(i)=\frac{1}{2}(\ln|i|+i\text{Arg}(i)+2k\pi i)=0+\frac{i}{2}\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{2}2k \pi i=\frac{i}{4}(4k\pi+\pi)$$

Comment: can u explain how did u get e^2x? I mean the second equation of your answer. thanks. @mannav

Comment: I made a mistake and I improved the answer. Do you understand now?

Comment: yup i understand now. but how did u find 1/4πi from last equation?

Comment: I didn't write this anywhere. Please, show me what you don't understand in the last equation

Comment: The last equation, $$ i/2*π/2 $$

Comment: Oh. Well, you have $\frac{i}{2}\text{Arg}(i)$. Think about the definition of the función $\text{Arg}$. The unique number $\alpha$ in the interval we mentioned which satisfies that $i=|i|(\cos\alpha +i\sin\alpha)$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Check it

Comment: cool. Understand everything now. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. And let me give you an advice: Write what you tried in the question and point what is your doubt, otherwise you will get bad reputation and people won't answer your questions

Answer (score 2):

Using $\tanh(iz)=i\tan(z)$ we find that we are looking for the solutions to $\tan(\frac{z}{i})=1$. $\tan(x)=1$ when $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi$. Thus our solutions are $z=i(\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi)=i\frac{\pi}{4}+in\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Edit: Removed a negative I had for some reason.